# How to get the previous bill number using the current bill number for a particular user in select query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an android application in which i face an issue that is i want to select the previous bill number as well as bill date of a particular user using the current bill number but the query which i am using is not giving me the exact answer can anyone tell me what query i have to use to get the previous bill number of a particular user using the current bill number i have to show only one bill number of that user.The table might have different users bill number.

Table:

```
 //bill label
private static final String BILL_ID = "billno";
private static final String BILL_DATE = "billdate";
private static final String BILL_FARMERNAME = "billfarmername";
private static final String BILL_MOBILENO = "mobileno";
private static final String BILL_PRODUCTTYPE = "producttype";
private static final String BILL_PRODUCTNO = "productcounts";
private static final String BILL_PRODUCTCOST = "productcost";
private static final String BILL_TOTALAMOUNT = "totalamount";
```

Table structure:

```
 //billdetails
    String CREATE_BILL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + BILL_LABELS + "("
            + BILL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + BILL_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + BILL_FARMERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + BILL_MOBILENO + " NUMERIC,"
            + BILL_PRODUCTTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + BILL_PRODUCTNO + " NUMERIC,"
            + BILL_PRODUCTCOST + " NUMERIC,"
            + BILL_TOTALAMOUNT + " NUMERIC" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BILL_TABLE);
```

Query used:

```
 String selectquery = "SELECT billdate FROM billlabel WHERE mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "' ORDER BY billdate DESC LIMIT 0,2";
```

Comment: how are you storing the date in SQLite, is it milliseconds as a text or formatted date?

Comment: @gopal_patil i am storing the date as Text in yyyy-mm-dd format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query since sqlite doesn't support TOP you can try this and check

```
 String selectquery = "SELECT billdate FROM billlabel WHERE billno < '" + billnumber + "' AND mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "' ORDER BY billdate DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the Date as a **Milliseconds** -> **DOUBLE** in SQLite database

```
 + BILL_DATE + " DOUBLE,"
```

and the perform your query with **ORDER BY** constraint.

```
String selectquery = "SELECT billdate FROM billlabel WHERE mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "' ORDER BY billdate DESC LIMIT 0,2";
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following query:
>
> `String selectquery = "SELECT billdate,billno FROM billlabel WHERE mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "' AND billno<'"+current_bill_no+"' ORDER BY billno DESC LIMIT 1";`
>
> This works only if previous Bill No < current bill no

Comment: SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

Answer (score -1):

Try it,

> SELECT TOP 1 [BillNumber] FROM [dbo].[tableName] WHERE [BillNumber] <
>   @CurrentBillNumber AND UserID = @UserID ORDER BY [BillNumber] DESC